# What is a difference between these two clicked() signals in PyQt?

Tags: python, button, pyqt, click, signals-slots

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(my_button, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), my_func)
```

and

```
my_button.clicked.connect(my_func)
```

I usually use the first option, but then I found the second one and want to know what is a difference between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first option is the [old-style signal and slot syntax](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/old_style_signals_slots.html), which is now obsolete. You can still use it in PyQt4, but it is not supported at all in PyQt5. The second option is the [new-style signal and slot syntax](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html), which can be used in PyQt5 and all recent versions of PyQt4 (it was introduced in v4.5).

The PyQt docs lists the following disadvantages of the old-style syntax:

> - It requires knowledge of the C++ types of signal arguments.
> - It is error prone in that if you mis-type the signal name or signature - then no exception is raised, either when the signal is
>     connected or emitted.
> - It is verbose.
> - It is not Pythonic.